# How to format c# object to display category and subcategory in json body?

Tags: .net, json, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, restful-url

I am calling restfulURL using webclient. I need to send json body as shown in below example. Can anyone help me with how to send Category & SubCategory in my json body.

What object (ex. List or IEnumerable) should i use, so jsonSerializer would convert it in the below format.

{
  "Address":{
   "Zipcode":"123",
   "City":"LA",
   "State":"CA",
   },
     "Category":{
                    "ID":1,
                    "Name":"",
                           "Subcategory":[{
                                       "Flag":false,
                                      "ID":123,
                                     "Name":"name"
                             }]
              },
  "Email":"email@email.com",
  "FirstName":"first",
  "LastName":"last",
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class Widget{
    public string Address{get; set;}
    public string City{get; set;}
    //other properties
    public Category Category {get; set;}
}

public class Subcategory{
   public int Id{get; set;}
   public string Name {get; set;}
}
public class Category{
    public int Id{get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public List<Subcategory> Subcategory {get; set;}
}
```

if you create a widget object and you serialize it, it should end up in the format you are looking for. I don't think you need to do anything special.

Comment: Thanks. Would it make difference if i use IEnumerable insted of List?

Comment: I don't think so- I know purists like to use Enumerable and internally they can have any sort of collection. Frankly I usually just end up using list-- thanks for marking as correct!

Answer (score 3):

```
public class Category
{
   public int Id{get; set;}
   public string Name {get; set;}
   public List<Category> SubCategories {get; set;}
}
```